# Reading file with Ruby returns strange output

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read in a `JSON` file with `Ruby` and the output is extremely strange. Here is the code that I am using:

```rb
require 'rubygems'

class ServiceCalls 

    def initialize ()

    end

    def getFile()

        Dir.entries('./json').each do |mFile|

            if mFile[0,1] != "."
                self.sendServiceRequest(mFile)
            end

        end
    end

    def sendServiceRequest(mFile)
        currentFile = File.new("./json/" + mFile, "r") 
        puts currentFile.read
        currentFile.close
    end



end

mServiceCalls = ServiceCalls.new
mServiceCalls.getFile
```

And here is the output:

```
Macintosh H??=A?v?P$66267945-2481-3907-B88A-1094AA9DAB6D??/??is32???????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????s8m+88888888???????89????????99?????????9:??????????:;??????????;=??????????=>??????????>????????????@??????????@A??????????AC??????????CD??????????DE??????????EE??????????E6OXdknnkdXO6ic118?PNG
bookmark88?A[DT>??A?@
                     ApplicationsMAMPhtdocsServiceTestAutomationMDXservicecatalog-verizon.json$4T??
                  `?
                   U?????l??????
                                Macintosh H??=A?v?P$66267945-2481-3907-B88A-1094?is32???????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????s8m+88888888???????89????????99?????????9:??????????:;??????????;=??????????=>??????????>????????????@??????????@A??????????AC??????????CD??????????DE??????????EE??????????E6OXdknnkdXO6ic118?PNG
UIEvolutions-MacBook-Pro-109:MDXServiceTesting Banderson$ ruby testmdxservices.rb
bookmark88?A?,P>??A?@
                     ApplicationsMAMPhtdocsServiceTestAutomationMDXservicecatalog-adaptation.json$4T??
                     `?
                      U?????l??????
                                   Macintosh H??=A?v?P$66267945-2481-3907-B88A-1094AA9DAB6D??/?<icns<?TOC his32?s8mic118il32?l8mic1?ic07ic13#ic08#ic14^?ic09_ic1?is32???????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????vvz???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????s8m+88888888???????89????????99?????????9:??????????:;??????????;=??????????=>??????????>????????????@??????????@A??????????AC??????????CD??????????DE??????????EE??????????E6OXdknnkdXO6ic118?PNG

IHDR szz?iCCPICC Profile(?T?k?P??e???:g >h?ndStC??kW??Z?6?!H??m\??$?~?ًo:?w?>?
                                                                             كo{?a???"L?"???4M'S??????9'??^??qZ?/USO???????^C+?hM??J&G@Ӳy???lt?o߫?c՚?
                                                                    ? ??5?"?Y?i\?΁?'&??.?<?ER/?dE?oc?ግ#?f45@?   ??B:K?@8?i??
                  ??s??_???雭??m?N?|??9}p?????_?A??pX6?5~B?$?&???ti??e??Y)%$?bT?3li?
    ??????P???4?43Y???P??1???KF????ۑ??5>?)?@????r??y??????[?:V???ͦ#??wQ?HB??d(??B
                                                                               a?cĪ?L"J??itTy?8?;(???Gx?_?^?[???????%׎??ŷ??Q???麲?ua??n?7???
                                                           Q???H^e?O?Q?u6?S??u
                                                                              ?2??%vX
     ???^?*l
O?????ޭˀq,>??S???%?L??d????B???1CZ??$M??9??P
                                            'w????\/????]???.r#???E|!?3?>_?o?a?۾?d?1Z?ӑ???z???'?=??????~+??cjJ?tO%mN?????
                                         |??-???bW?O+
o?
  ^?
    I?H?.?;???S?]?i_s9?*p???.7U^??s.?3u?
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Do I need to specify what type of encoding I'm using? I have tried to read the file with `gets`, `sysread`, and another I can't remember.

Comment: You're reading the directory. Stuff like this is trivial to debug: print out the filename--don't *assume* what you think is happening is happening, *verify what is actually happening*.

Comment: No, I'm trying to read the file in the directory. I read the directory to get the files, then read each file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. Did you print out each file you're passing like I suggested??? .g., `puts mFile`? Also, not a great variable name. Oh, is that what the check for "." is supposed to do? You still need to check your assumptions, IMO, unless your JSON files are supposed to contain things like the strings we see here--without knowing anything about the files, we don't even know if it's wrong, you know.

Comment: BlaineOmega: I think the file you are reading has an unusual encoding.  (The question marks are usually an indication that your terminal detected symbols it cannot print.)  Can you find out which encoding it has?  Maybe open it in an editor or `cd json ; file *`

Comment: You are right @philip I "reloaded" the files into the directory and now it works fine. I'm not sure if something happened when I "drag-and-dropped" them into the folder the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure why but I believe it is the './json' path that is causing the issue. I tried the script on my Windows XP machine and got similar results.

However, when I rewrote the script to include `File.dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `'./'` it worked. I also cleaned up some of the code.

```
class ServiceCalls 

    def get_file
        dirname = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'json')
        Dir.entries(dirname).each do |file|
            unless file.start_with? '.'
                File.open(File.join(dirname, file), 'r') {|f| puts f.read}
            end
        end
    end
end

sc = ServiceCalls.new
sc.get_file
```

`__FILE__` is the path of the current script. [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-join) uses system independent path separators. [`File.open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open), if you pass it a block, will actually close the file for you when it completes the block. [`String#start_with?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) is a cleaner way than using `[0,1]` to get the first element of a string.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dir.entries('./json').each do |mFile|
  next if ['.', '..'].include?(mFile)
  self.sendServiceRequest(mFile)
```

Comment: The `/*` is not required. [Dir#entries](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-entries)